# Align DIVs horizontal and vertically - CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have the following set up for my webpage:

HTML:

```
<div id="headercontent">
    <div id="topnav"></div>
    <div id="dailycalendar"></div>
    <div id="headerimage"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#headercontent { width: 990px; height: 162px; position: relative; margin: 0 0 0 0; vertical-align: top; padding: 0px; }
#topnav { float: left; width: 720px; height: 50px; }
#dailycalendar { float: left; width: 720px; height: 112px; }
#headerimage { float: right; width: 270px; }
```

I want the `div` tags within the following order using CSS and cross browser capability:

```
----------------- ----------------
-    topnav     - -              -
----------------- -  headerimage -
----------------- -              -
- dailycalendar - -              -
----------------- ----------------
```

Comment: Wrap the `topnav` and `dailycalendar` to a div, and float that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed it by changing the order of the divs, and setting a height on headerimage:

```
<div id="headercontent">
    <div id="headerimage"></div>
    <div id="topnav"></div>
    <div id="dailycalendar"></div>
</div>

#headerimage { float: right; width: 270px; height:100%; background-color:green }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pyXer/

Comment: Indeed, this should be satisfactory!

Comment: Thanks mate!  Good solution!  I did not want to wrap the `topnav` and `dailycalendar`within another div like the other comment suggested.